# Augment a bounded Latin Hypercube in R

Tags: r

I have created a table of parameter sets sampling the parameter ranges using a Latin Hypercube.

```
library(tgp)
rect <- rbind(x1 = c(25,500),               
              x2 = c(50,5000),                  
              x3 = c(0.05,0.95),                
              x4 = c(1,20),                     
              x5 = c(1,250),  
              x6   = c(1,5),  
              x7  = c(0.05,0.95), 
              x9   = c(0.01,1000) )

# Define number of samples
n <- 1000

#Generate parameters
set.seed(123)
parameters <- lhs(n, rect)
```

Now, how can I augment the LH adding x10, which range is between 0.01 and 0.5, without changing the other parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but does `parameters.new <- lhs(n, rbind(rect, x10 = c(0.01, 0.5)))` achieve what you want?

Comment: @dbaupp, make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rbind` makes a new table, it doesn't modify the table(s) it is being called on; so the following works:

```
parameters.new <- lhs(n, rbind(rect, x10 = c(0.01, 0.5)))
```